# Can I report on an Opportunity with a custom object with a Related_To_Account field?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have a custom object (Journal__c) which relates to Account. An Opportunity can only reference one Account.

Journal__c has fields: `Related_To_Account__c` and `My_Value__c`.

I want a report which shows:

```
Opportunity Name    My_Value__c
Fred Bloggs-Opp 1   2800
Bill Gates-Opp 3    1967
```

I have tried creating a custom report type but cannot seem to relate the three objects `Opportunity`, `Account` and `Journal__c`. I thought there would be an obvious join possible from Opp-Account-Journal.

What is the correct way to construct a custom report type which will handle fields related in this way?

Answer (score 0):

As the Journal__c and Opportunity objects are both parented by the Account, you cannot create a report type to handle the related objects in the way you are suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been reviewing page  [Reporting on a Parent Object and More than One Child Object](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212483)  and that may help.

Comment: Yes, a joined report is the way to go here, since report types can't do this.